# 11.10, get purple screen, hybrid graphics related?

Tags: 11.10, dual-boot, samsung

After spending countless hours (patience running), I am now at a loss.

I freshly wubi installed 11.10, optimized it with almost everything running perfectly. Did several reboots, in between Windows and Ubuntu. Today, it won't boot into Ubuntu and the splash page doesn't pop up.

Background: Samsung Series 7, i7 and ATI 6750m card. I installed the prop/ATI drivers for the video card manually, so fglrx is there. Not open-source drivers.

Symptoms:

- will get into grub by holding shift
- the kernel that I upgraded to 3.2.2ish? won't boot past 'loading initial ramdisk...'
- when I try older kernels (3.2.0-generic-.12 or something like that, default kernel), the whole thing just hangs and becomes unresponsive. Nothing works, no keyboard, fan turns off, can't power off with the button, and r e s i u o doesn't work. I just have to let the battery run down (battery is behind screws) and cross my fingers that the cpu doesn't melt into a  $1300 brick.

I want to say it's related to hybrid graphics, but I honestly have no clue what's going on. I am entirely frustrated, after 4 reinstall attempts and thinking it was finally working right.

I'm a relative linux newbie, so I don't know what to do in grub to trouble shoot. Is there anything I can do in grub to make sure it's not a driver issue. Is it a driver issue? Someone please, desperately, help me, before I punt kick this thing back to the Microsoft store.

Comment: To switch off without letting the battery run down, hold the power switch down for about 10 seconds. This works on my identical Chronos laptop. As for helping you, I'd suspect Wubi more than fglrx, but since I'm running 12.04 on mine, I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: just to be extra clear, the entire machine becomes unresponsive. holding down the power button for about 5 minutes didn't do anything either...

Comment: Sounds like a hardware fault, Denny. Holding on the power button isn't an O/S feature - it's a hardware one. No matter what state the laptop is in, the BIOS should cut power after about 5 seconds.

Comment: Do you have a better/alternative soultion? I'd like to run linux on this laptop somehow. is 12.04 a better fit?

Comment: An alternative for shutdown - no. Like I say, it's a BIOS function to power off the system after 5-10 seconds of holding on the button. As an alternative for the Hybrid graphics, yes, I've had good luck with 12.04, and it recognises the touchpad much better too (two finger scrolilng, two finger tap for right click and so on), but it's not perfect. It's a real pain getting fglrx installed for example. I'll try to document what I did when I get back to my PC on Wednesday.

Comment: I went instead with a virtual box install. It seems to work for now, but that's the best way I can handle this without launching my computer across the freeway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a issue of hybrid graphics,
I've run 11.10 on my Lenovo W520 for a while, and I've experienced the same, no matter what graphics setting.

I switched to gentoo 2 weeks ago, and the issue is gone.
I think it's a problem of the EFI boot subsystem (which I didn't include in my gentoo installation).

Greetins Christian

Comment: any recommendations then? I may try my luck with a virtual machine version...

Comment: try booting with a live cd

Answer (score 0):

I cant give an exact answer for whats actually wrong but from the looks it seems that we can put the blame on fglrx, I've used fglrx for a long time and have run in to troubles mainly because of it's closed nature. fglrx doesn't get updated as soon as new kernel versions get released, my suggestion is that you revert to some kernel from the Ubuntu repos(3.0.0.16 is latest I guess) and then give a try to use fglrx on that. To do this try to get in to recovery mode, then drop in to root shell and do `sudo apt-get remove fglrx` it should bring things back to normal if not try deleting `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` (if its there fglrx has a habit of making one). It should do the trick, if not can you post the `dmesg` output? You can write to file by `dmesg > file`

Comment: but i cant even get into recovery mode. not sure how to get to root shell...

Comment: Doesn't your Grub give you a selection called "recovery mode"? You should see something like that in the grub menu. After selecting it, you can get in to the root shell. But even if it doesn't load, you are better off just backing up your stuff using a Live CD and reinstalling the OS. After that keep the standard kernel(you may upgrade) but don't go for mainline or newer ones since ATI does not release drivers targeting the newest kernels(they might work, and they might not work). ATI says it supports switching now so you can just install it and see, if its the same you'd need to contact ATI.